# Make recursive API call using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, recursion, retrofit

I'm implementing pagination concept in my android application to store a very large
data in sqlite database.

I want to make a call to an API using retrofit.
The api will return a flag if we reach the end of the table. If yes I will store
result in local database if not make another (recursive call) until we reach the end of the table

Once I debugged it the api is called twice only while it should make another
call based on my logic.

The code reach the end of the `OnResponse` callback and it never get called again

```
 public void getDataOffset (final int processType, final int offset) {
  try {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Upload , 
    Please wait...", true);

    String url = mUrl ;
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setEmployeeID(EmployID);
    request.setOffset(offset);

    IAPI iAPI = Global.getIAPI(url,420,420);
    Call<RetrofitCallResponse.OffsetResponse> call = iAPI.GetDataOffset(request);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<RetrofitCallResponse.OffsetResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RetrofitCallResponse.OffsetResponse> call, Response<RetrofitCallResponse.OffsetResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

                if (!response.body().HasError) {

                    if (response.body().DataList().size() <= 0) {
                        hasError = true;
                        errorMessage = "Empty.";
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        callback.onCallComplete(hasError,errorMessage);
                    }


                    mList.addAll(response.body().DataList());


                    if (response.body().IsEndOfTable) {
                        DBConnections dbConnections = new DBConnections(context, null);
                        boolean isInserted;
                        isInserted = dbConnections.insertOffset(mList,processType,context);
                        dbConnections.close();

                        if (!isInserted) {
                            hasError = true;
                            errorMessage = "Result couldn't be saved locally";
                        }

                        hasError = false;
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        callback.onCallComplete(hasError,errorMessage);

                    } else {
                        getDataOffset (processType , mList.size());
                    }
                } else {
                    hasError = true;
                    errorMessage =  response.body().ErrorMessage;
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    callback.onCallComplete(hasError,errorMessage);
                }


            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                hasError = true;
                errorMessage =  "Response Code : " + response.code() + " " + response.toString();
            }

            // progressDialog.dismiss();
            // callback.onCallComplete(hasError,errorMessage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RetrofitCallResponse.OffsetResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            hasError = true;
            errorMessage = t.toString();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            callback.onCallComplete(hasError,errorMessage);
        }
    });


} catch (Exception e ) {
    hasError = true;
    errorMessage = e.toString();
    callback.onCallComplete(hasError,errorMessage);
}
}
```